# Cartesian product of contraints

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Using a lifted version of `(,)` for the cartesian product of constraint seems to work until you want to use the fact that it's cartesian, which GHC seems unaware of.

GHC seems to treat `'(,)` as just an monoïdal product, leading to the error

```
• Could not deduce: ax ~ '(a, x) arising from a use of ‘Dict’
  from the context: (a ~ Fst ax, x ~ Snd ax)
```

Although `Fst` and `Snd` are not just any projections, they are the cartesian one.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableSuperClasses #-}

module SO.SO_CartesianProduct where

data Dict c = c => Dict

type family Fst (ij :: (i, j)) :: i
type instance Fst '(i, j) = i

type family Snd (ij :: (i, j)) :: j
type instance Snd '(i, j) = j

class (a ~ Fst ax, x ~ Snd ax) => IsProd ax a x where d :: Dict (ax ~ '(a, x))

instance (a ~ Fst ax, x ~ Snd ax) => IsProd ax a x where
  d = Dict -- • Could not deduce: ax ~ '(a, x) arising from a use of ‘Dict’
  --   from the context: (a ~ Fst ax, x ~ Snd ax)
```

An attempt to instruct GHC of that fact fails

```hs
-- Fails
instance (a ~ Fst ax, x ~ Snd ax) => (ax ~ '(a, x))

-- • Class ‘~’ does not support user-specified instances
-- • In the instance declaration for ‘(ax ~ '(a, x))’typ
```

Is there anyway to instruct GHC that it's actually cartesian, or to get a product recognized as cartesian by GHC in some way ?

Comment: If you could manually write `~` instances then it would be _very_ easy to cause extremely weird failures downstream...

Comment: @leftaroundabout I can imagine. because instances are global also (?). but compiler plugins are allowed, so it happens that you need to trust better authorities than Haskell compiler, however smart he is..

Comment: It is in fact not the case that `ax ~ (Fst ax, Snd ax)`, because `Any :: k`. Frustrating, but the current state of things nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the pair into "canonical form" (any pair `p` can be written in canonical form as `(fst p, snd p)`), this fixes the type error:

```
type family Canonical p where
  Canonical p = '(Fst p, Snd p)

class (a ~ Fst ax, x ~ Snd ax) => IsProd ax a x where d :: Dict (Canonical ax ~ '(a, x))

instance (a ~ Fst ax, x ~ Snd ax) => IsProd ax a x where
  d = Dict
```

Incidentally, I recommend using closed type families (like how `Canonical` is written) where possible (when you don't need the type family to be potentially extended later on). I've found it helps with certain problems and makes things easier.

I'm not sure if this will entirely fit with the rest of your problem, though. It's possible that, even though this fixes the type error, it may still not integrate with the rest of what you want to do.

Comment: Good advice for closed type family. thank you. that fact that any pair can be written as in a canonical form is precisely the cartesian property. I don't find any way to convince GHC of that fact, although he has all the info. I wonder if there is a way to force it (unsafeCoerce ? other ? ) if that's not possible within its kind/type system.

Comment: @nicolas `unsafeCoerce` might be possible, I’m not sure. Could you provide more details of the larger problem you’re solving? That might help.

Comment: I would like to define an instance for a cartesian product of instances, where the class has an associated constraint. so I would like the associated contraint to be the cartesian product of the associated constraints. If I can't have the pair from the components (and not just the components from the pair like we do with `Fst` and `Snd`), I have to carry that product around, and I have to access the component by projecting them out. I would prefer not to carry the product, and access the components directly. this boils down to having access to a `(ax ~ '(Fst ax, Snd ax)` somewhere.

Comment: @nicolas Hmm, so something like this `instance (Assoc'd (a, b), C a, C b) => C (a, b) where ...`?

Comment: It probably has to be done outside of the normal type class system. with a `unsafeCoerce` (hopefully) or a "ghc plugin"... If the same mechanism than `reflect` of Oleg applies to `cart2 :: Dict (ax ~ '(Fst2 ax, Snd2 ax))
cart2 = unsafeCoerce (??) `

Comment: @nicolas The problem is, as Daniel Wagner says, I think there are actually situations where that fails (specifically because `Any` exists). Are you *sure* that there is no broader problem that you're trying to solve here? This seems like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) and maybe we could help you solve the underlying problem of the larger goal if you can give us more details on it (if there is one).

Comment: it fails.. in the type system. `unsafeCoerce` is a way out of the type system. my larger problem is that I want to get rid of keeping the product kind hanging around. I already have a solution for the bigger problem : keep the product kind, and pick out the components from it when I need them. I will find an exemple to make this more concrete

Comment: For instance here : https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hask-0/docs/Hask-Category-Polynomial.html  you have `class (Ob p (Fst a), Ob q (Snd a)) => ProductOb p q a` and not, say, `class (Product (Ob p, Ob q) a) => ProductOb p q a` for some `Product` building a product of constraints. you could write it, but then it becomes impossible to use as you can't build the product of constraints from the individual components of that product. Now products are "special" you can't apply to them the same mechanic which exist somewhere else. this hurts abstraction